# (NO anaconda) Import Error undefined symbol PyFPE_jbuf

Tags: python, numpy, import

Trying to make python work in order to use qutip is leading me to self distruction.
Today's new issue is in importing `numpy`. I checked all the other stacks about this error, I couldn't get it fixed. I'm pretty puzzled also because the only thing i did was installing all the packages and checking their installation importing them. The only thing i put hand on was `PYTHONPATH` to fix another error.
 I'm using `python2.7.12` . 
The problem is that when i `command`

```
import numpy
```

The ouput is:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 201, in <module>
     from . import random
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/random/__init__.py", line 99, in <module>
     from .mtrand import *
 ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/random/mtrand.so: undefined symbol: PyFPE_jbuf
```

What does it mean? How do i fix the problem?
`Numpy` is at its newest version, i installed it with `apt-get` first and then with `pip`.

Comment: I don't think its the same case

Comment: you said that you installed using `apt-get` and then `pip`, but befor installing `numpy` using `pip`, did you uninstalled the old one which is installed by `apt-get`

Comment: no. I tryed installing it only with pip, but there was no numpy folder in .../python2.7/dist-packages/  so it didn't work! But if i install it only with apt-get it gives me other errors

Comment: even if i uninstall it with pip so that the only installation is that of apt-get, it gives me the same error

Answer (score 0):

These sorts of incompatibilities are much easier to control in a virtualenv (or a conda env). Just make a clean virtualenv and install things into it with pip. (Pip >= 8.1 will likely make it even easier).

Edit: and never *ever* do `sudo pip`